# Applying an equation to specific rows of an array and concatenating the answers to an array

Tags: matlab

```
% Example

array = [1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0];
for i = 1:length(array)
    if i(1) ~= 0
        array_mag_1 = sqrt(array(1)^2 + array(2)^2 + array(3)^2);
        if exist('array_mag_1','var') == 1
            new_array = array_mag_1;
        end
    elseif i(4) ~= 0
        array_mag_2 = sqrt(array(4)^2 + array(5)^2 + array(6)^2);
        if exist('array_mag_2', 'val') == 1
            new_array = cat(array_mag_1, array_mag_2);
        end
    elseif i(7) ~= 0
        array_mag_3 = sqrt(array(7)^2 + array(8)^2 + array(9)^2);
        if exist('array_mag_3', 'val') == 1
            new_array = cat(array_mag_1, array_mag_2, array_mag_3);
        end
    end
end

for j = 1:length(new_array)
    if j > 0
        cat_new_array = new_array(j);
    else
        return
    end
end
```

Whats the best way to take sets of 3 elements (if it's a nonzero), find the magnitude, and concatenate that to 'cat_new_array', then skip the remaining zeros? I'm also finding that it keeps the first 'array_mag_1' even though it has nonzero values in array(4). I'm new to coding, so I apologize for any confusion. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your question is not entirely clear. could you give us a better, reproducible example? 
Also, check the [vecnorm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vecnorm.html) to calculate the norm of each row on the array.

Comment: I've edited the example. I hope that clears up what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you for the suggestion, that simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
array = [1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 7 0 0]
array_non_zero = find(array);
cat_new_array = [];
for i=1:floor(numel(array_non_zero)/3)
    cat_new_array = [cat_new_array, norm(array(array_non_zero((i-1)*3+1:i*3)))]
end
```

This code takes the non zero elements from array 3 by 3 and calculates the norm of each set of 3 elements. I didn't get clear from your question if that's what you need.

Comment: This works for i = 1, but when i = 2 it looks like array_non_zero(2:8). What I'm trying to do is take the norm(array(array_non_zero(1:3)....array_non_zero(4:6)... array_non_zero(7:9))) then concatenate each norm value into a new array, in this case cat_new_array =  [1 x 3] array... I hope this clears things up a bit, but thank you for the advice!

Comment: That's why I made (i-1) *3+1:i*3, when i=1, then array(1:3). When i=2, then array(4:5), and so on. Check that max value of i is numel(array_non_zero) /3

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in functions [vecnorm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vecnorm.html) to calculate the vector norm of each row of the array and the [nonzeros](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html) function to get only the nonzero values.

```
A = [1 2 3;4 5 6;0 0 0;7 8 9;0 0 0];
cat_new_array = nonzeros(vecnorm(A,2,2))

> cat_new_array = 
>     3.7417
>     8.7750
>     13.9284
```